# Is it possible to get the start and end byte locations, relative to the device, for a file?

Tags: linux, ext4

Assuming that /dev/sda1 has an ext4 filesystem. On that filesystem, there exists a file: /foobar.txt .

Is it possible to determine the byte range (or list of fragmented ranges) that /foobar.txt occupies on /dev/sda1 ?

Comment: What's the back story to your question?

Comment: Just curious if it's technically possible. I think technically the file descriptors in linux must do this at the lower level, so I'm wondering if it's information that can be exposed to a user-level application.

Comment: Without cracking into the hard disk firmware, you have no reliable way of knowing where a file is stored physically on a disk.

Comment: `# debugfs -R "blocks path/to/file" /dev/sda1`

Comment: @EEAA I guess the OP meant relative to the logical device visible to the Linux Kernel, not hard disc itself.